# Epoch to date UTC+3

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I used this code to convert epoch to human readable date

```
var timestamp = 1293683278; 
var date = new Date(timestamp*1000); 
var year = date.getFullYear(); 
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
var day = date.getDate(); 
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes(); 
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
```

I need to change it to UTC+3 how can i do this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Date constructor treats time values as UTC. Date objects only ever represent UTC time, the "local" values produced by *toString* methods use system settings to determine the offset to use, but that's only for the sake of producing a timestamp, it doesn't change the underlying Date or its time value.

If you want a specific offset, you can choose an appropriate [IANA location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) such as Africa/Nairobi, which is +3 all year round, and produce a timestamp using [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), e.g.

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleString('default',{timeZone:'Africa/Nairobi', timeZoneName:'short'})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious - but couldn't you just append 3 hours onto your timestamp before formatting it with your existing code. I'm curious if there's some date/calendar subtlety where this wouldn't reliably work.

```
const THREE_HOURS_IN_MS = 3*60*60*1000;
var date = new Date(timestamp*1000 + THREE_HOURS_IN_MS); 

// rest of your code stays unchanged
var year = date.getFullYear(); 
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
var day = date.getDate(); 
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes(); 
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment.js` `utcOffset` to achieve this easily:

```
const moment = require("moment");

const timestamp = 1619071948 * 1000;

console.log(moment(timestamp).utcOffset(180).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ"));
```

The offset provided is in minutes

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/